# How can i retrieve the formated text from DB and display it in HTML using the PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a form that has a field called *post content*, I am using WYSIWYG Editor to allow the end-user to format the text before saving it or update into the database. the problem that I am facing when it retrieves such content using echo like:

```
<p><?php echo $post_content ?></p>
```

it will be displayed like that to the end-user.

This <b>Course </b>is Wonderful. I encourage everyone to take it.

So how can i display the retrieved data correctly as per their formates?

Comment: Whatever your code is doing to store the html codes will need to be reversed. If you `var_dump($post_content)`, what is in it? Encoded html, presumably, so your example above probably contains `&gt;` which you will need to translate back to `>`, and so on. So, first find out what you do to encode it for storage, that should give you a clue how to reverse it.

Comment: My guess: you have a universal "escape" function which tries to escape backslashes, HTML, quotes, all at once. Don't do that. Escaping should be based on where you want to output to, and database queries should use parameterised queries (often referred to as prepared statements) not any kind of escaping.

Comment: you are right. it's stored with &gt; .. so how can I retrieve it as < or >?

Comment: htmlspecialchars_decode  - See [official_documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Comment: shall i use htmlspecialchars_decode()?

Comment: Yes, you are right ...

Comment: Yes, this is the function you want I believe, but be careful --- Actually escaping special characters are required to prevent hacking. Imagine if someone put <script>window.location.href=xxxxxxx</script> into your site and if you display the whole string without escaping, it can be executed and redirect the user to the target site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```php
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($post_content) ?></p>
```